# Check if any array inside another array contains a value from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays aa = [[value, value2], [value3, value4]]
and I need to check if my new array a = [value2, value7]
includes any value from aa
I had tried this code and then i tried with adding .every to the aa but doesnt work. what should i do

```
a.some(r=> aa.includes(r))

a.some(r=> aa.every.includes(r))
```

Comment: `a.some(value => aa.some(inner => inner.includes(value))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a nested array, you will want to use [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) on the `aa` array first. This will convert:

```
[[value, value2], [value3, value4]]
```

...to:

```
[value, value2, value3, value4]
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const aa = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
const a = [2, 7];

// Flatten nested arrays
const aaFlat = aa.flat();

console.log(a.some(x => aaFlat.includes(x)));
```